# Timezone for London

Tags: .net, timezone, timezone-offset

I am trying to use a single Time zone for a given city e.g. London, so I can run a task always at a given London time regardless of Daylight Saving.

So, in short

task can run 4pm London time in winter and summer.

I used Central Standard Time for setting a task for New York but I can see that my task is running an hour later since New York Daylight Saving has started a week back.

Does anyone know if such single TimeZones exist for .Net which represent local time for a city?

I dont want to use BST and GMT as I will need to configure it twice.

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "regardless of Daylight Saving"? For some parts of the question it sounds like you *do* want to observe daylight saving, but in the New York example the "but" makes it sound like you *didn't* want that. The Windows time zone IDs are very confusing - just because it's got "standard" in the name doesn't mean it's only standard time :(

Comment: Hi Jon, I think I was able to show my intention with the New York example (not so much by explaining my question). So we have a task which goes out to various financial vendors and pulls data for a specific hour and the data can be different based on the hour. The data gets published in the local time; so for London it gets published every hour but we are only interested in selective hours e.g. 4pm and if we by any chance pull 3pm's data or 5pm's data, our calculations will be incorrect.

Comment: @Jon - yes, in case of New York - Eastern Standard Time did not work (as you pointed out - the word 'Standard' fooled me).

Comment: @RobertDinaro - You might want to read through [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info). There's a section on "The Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database" that explains this very issue with the names.

Comment: I'm still confused about what you want. If you want the *actual, observed local time* then the `TimeZoneInfo` for "Eastern Standard Time" *should* have worked for you. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The Windows time zone ID for London is `"GMT Standard Time"`.  Yes, the name is confusing, but it does indeed correctly represent GMT and BST as used in the UK, and the transitions between them.

However, If you are running .NET Core on a non-Windows OS, then you will need to use the IANA time zone ID of `"Europe/London"` instead.

Both of these work with the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` method, on their respective operating systems.

Lastly, if you are designing your code to be cross-platform, you may wish to use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library, which will allow you to use either form of identifier on any platform.

Comment: GMT Standard Time will be tested thoroughly this coming Monday as currently, we are pulling data at 4pm London time and comes Monday, I am hoping that it will continue to do so.

Comment: However, what I am trying to get to is a list of unified time zones for every region which observes Daylight Saving (move the clock forward or backward). So when I configure my task; I use this unified time zone for a given city like New York and then the data is pulled let's say 4pm every day.

Comment: the app is written using .Net Standard and it is running on a Windows server.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "unified time zones".  If you want a list of all time zones, `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` will do the trick.  You can then use the `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` function to check if it's DST for a specific point in time.  What you can't do is assume that DST works the same all over the world - it doesn't.

Comment: Also, if you want a list of all IANA time zones, there's one on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  If you want to know how those map back to Windows time zones, the CLDR has data [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

Comment: And finally, if you're writing for .NET Standard, you might be better off using IANA time zones even if you're on Windows.  Who knows - one day you might want to deploy to Linux servers.  You can either use them directly with [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) (via `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb`), or you can use them with [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) (via `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo`).

Comment: thanks Matt - I think GMT Standard Time mislead me to believe that there are time zones which reflect the current/local of a given region. As you said and I noticed it with Eastern Standard Time, this assumption was not true. I will look into IANA time zones.